# Poor frequency of impressions Interstitial ads

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, ads, interstitial

In my application, after Splash, Interstitial ads are shown, I do the following on SplashActivity, I load it and after switching to MainActivity I show it, I do everything like this:

SplashActivity

```
class ActivitySplash : AppCompatActivity(), Ads.AdsCallback {
    private val DELAY = 8000L
    private var isAdsOpen = false
    private lateinit var sBinding: ActivitySplashBinding

    private val liveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    override fun adsLoaded() {
        super.adsLoaded()
        isAdsOpen = true
        liveData.postValue(true)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sBinding = ActivitySplashBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = sBinding.root
        setContentView(view)

        Ads.preload(this, BuildConfig.ADS_INTERSTITIAL)
        Ads.setAdsCallBack(this)

        setLiveData()

        liveData.observe(this, {
            if (it) {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        })

    }

    private fun setLiveData() {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            if (!isAdsOpen) {
                    liveData.postValue(true)
            }
        }, DELAY)
    }

}
```

MainActivity В onCreate()

```
Ads.showInter(this, null)
```

Ads

```
object Ads {
private const val ALLOWABLE_AMOUNT_REQUEST = 2

    private var requestInterAdCount = 0
    private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    private var mAdIsLoading: Boolean = false

    private fun loadAd(context: Context, adsId: String) {
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        InterstitialAd.load(context, adsId, adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(onAdFailedToLoad: LoadAdError) {
                mInterstitialAd = null
                if (requestInterAdCount < ALLOWABLE_AMOUNT_REQUEST) {
                    requestInterAdCount += 1
                    loadAd(context, adsId)
                }
            }

            override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
                adsCallback?.adsLoaded()
                mAdIsLoading = true

                mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        mInterstitialAd = null
                        mAdIsLoading = false
                    }

                    override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: AdError?) {
                        mInterstitialAd = null
                        mAdIsLoading = false
                    }

                    override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        mAdIsLoading = false

                    }
                }

            }
        })

    }

    fun preload(context: Context, adsId: String) {
        adsCallback = null
        loadAd(context, adsId)

    }

    interface AdsCallback {
        fun adsLoaded() {}
    }

    private var adsCallback: AdsCallback? = null

    fun setAdsCallBack(adsCallback: AdsCallback) {
        this.adsCallback = adsCallback
    }

    fun showInter(activity: Activity?, adsSplashCallback: AdsCallback?) {
        this.adsCallback = adsCallback
        if (mAdIsLoading && mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd?.show(activity!!)
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is in the frequency of impressions, it is almost two times less than in other places of the application, although I use the same code, it seems that in half of the cases it either does not load or does not show ads, but I cannot understand why this is happening. Please tell me what could be wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: You can not do anything about it as per my knowledge. Google shows the ad (if the ads are available.) Many a times, there come situations when google does not have any ads to show. So its pretty normal.

Comment: @rootass I understand this, I'm wondering if I have an error in my code that gets in the way, in cases where there is something to show

Comment: Looks good to me.